# Is there a way to "hibernate" a linux container

Tags: docker

Say you had a bunch of wordpress containers running on a machine with each application sitting behind cache. Is there a way to stop a container and start it only if the url is not found in cache?

Comment: can you elaborate "only if the url is not found in cache"?

Comment: If you search for "docker orchestration"  you will maybe find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd provides a [Socket Activation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) feature that can activate a service on tcp connection and proxy the connection in. [Atlassian have a detailed article on using it with Docker](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/03/docker-systemd-socket-activation/).

I don't believe systemd has the ability to stop the service when there is no activity. You will need something that can close down the service after there are no connections left being served. This could be done in the wordpress app container or externally via systemd on the host.

Some more socket reading from the systemd developer:

http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activated-containers.html
http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation2.html
http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html

Comment: This be exactly what I was looking for. Thank ye.